# Printwriter does not seem to output to specified file after I add a while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, printwriter

I am in the early stages of a project for school and have already run into a bug. If I simply export the array list contents using the for loop without the while loop everything works fine, but when I want to use the while loop so that I can provide options, the output text file doesn't contain anything as if the program simply didn't do anything but create an empty text file. I am very confused.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class studentProcessor
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
   {  
      PrintStream pr=System.out;
      String inputFileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input file:");
      String outputFileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Output file:");
      File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
      Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);
      ArrayList<Student>student = new ArrayList<Student>();
      while (in.hasNextLine())
      {
          student.add(new Student(in.nextInt(), in.next(), in.nextDouble()));
      }
      in.close();
      boolean done=false;
      while (!done)
        {
            String m=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the number for the action which you would like to perform." +
                "\n1. Add new student(s)\n2. Remove student(s)\n3. Update student's data\n4. Search for student" +
                "\n5. Sort students\n6. Create GPA report\n7. Output information to a .txt file\n0. Exit");
            if (m.equals("1"))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Add new student(s)");
            }
            else if (m.equals("2"))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Remove student(s)");
            }
            else if (m.equals("3"))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Update student's data");
            }
            else if (m.equals("4"))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Search for a student");
            }
            else if (m.equals("5"))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sort students");
            }
            else if (m.equals("6"))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Create GPA report");
            }
            else if (m.equals("7"))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Output information to a .txt file");
                out.println("The students' information is listed below:");
                for (Student Stu:student)
                {
                    out.println(Stu.getId()+" "+Stu.getLName()+" "+Stu.getGpa());
                }
            }
            else if (m.equals("0"))
            {
                System.exit(0);
                done=true;
            }
            else 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have not entered a valid command, try again.");
            }
        }
      out.close();
   }
}
```

and here is the Student class I am using.

```
class Student
{ 
 private int id;
 private String lName;
 private double gpa;

 public Student (int studentId, String studentLName, double studentGpa)
   { 
     id=studentId;
     lName=studentLName;
     gpa=studentGpa;
   }

 public int getId()
   { return id; }

 public String getLName()
   { return lName; }

 public double getGpa()
   { return gpa; }

 public void setId(int id)
   { this.id=id; }

 public void setLName(String lName)
   { this.lName=lName; }

 public void setGpa(double gpa)
   { this.gpa=gpa; }

}
```

thanks for any help =]

EDIT: this is the new section of the code that works with printwriter now. thanks for all the help!

```
else if (m.equals("7"))
        {
            String outputFileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Designate an output file for student information:");
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);
            out.println("The students are listed below:");
            for (Student Stu:student)
            {
                out.println(Stu.getId()+" "+Stu.getLName()+" "+Stu.getGpa());
            }
            out.close();
        }
```

Comment: Why do you have System.exit(0); Setting done to false will cause the program to terminate and hopefully close the outfile properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flush your output stream after writing to it:

```
out.flush();
```

In addition, you will want to create your output stream when the user selects your write option (7). Otherwise you will write the records to the same file repeatedly. So something more like this:

```
     } else if (m.equals("7")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
              "Output information to a .txt file");
        final PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);
        out.println("The students' information is listed below:");
        for (Student Stu : student) {
           out.println(Stu.getId() + " " + Stu.getLName() + " "
                 + Stu.getGpa());
        }
        out.close();
     }
```

Comment: to continue my comment from another answer, i moved the out.close() to the location you showed and it works well now. idk if it is solely where i placed the out.close or if it is because i moved the initializing of the string for the out file as well. i will post an edit of what i did that seems to work

Comment: i want to ask, though, does the 'final' before PrintWriter make a huge difference in how the code runs? sorry, I'm a newbie and this is my first endeavor into a program this complex.

Comment: Tagging variables with final can provide a boost to your program - since it allows the compiler to make certain kind of optimizations. It's not a killer if you leave it out though.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the line with out.close is never being called.

The System.exit method terminates your application before closing the print writer.

You should use a try finally block for closing your resources.

Also your code would be clearer if the System.exit call was at the end of the method instead of in the while loop.  You're already using a boolean to terminate the loop, so let it terminate, and continue to the rest of your code.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the system.exit() i forgot to remove it after i changed to boolean. i also figured out my issue and initialize the string for the output file within the loop exactly when i want to use it instead of at the beginning of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried flush()ing the PrintWriter before closing it?

Comment: closing will flush the writer, the problem is that the close method is not being called.